# Java - How to send certain number of http requests at a time while queueing others

Tags: java, httprequest, discord

I am working on a discord bot which allows you to search for an anime using the Jihan Rest API for myanimelist. However, the API only allows 2 requests per second, and any breach of that will result in an IP ban. Therefore, I have to program the search function (which will send the requests to the Jihan API) to the only search for 2 things at once. However, this is more complicated than it seems.

For those who do not know how the Discord API works, there is an overridden message received method which is run whenever a user, who is on a server which contains the bot, sends a message. This method also kind of acts like a thread because a separate instance of it runs for every user who sends a message.

This complicates the program since if more than 3 users search for an anime at the same time, I need to somehow send two requests while queuing the third one until one of the other two returns a response. But then, I also have to return that response to the instance of the `messageReceived` method which sent it.

[image]

**I don't really have any code to show for this one. I just would appreciate an explanation, pseudocode, or java code for how to approach this problem. Thank you very much!**

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I got your problem completely right, but seems that you can solve this with consumer/ producer pattern with a blocking queue in between.

So when a user sends a message, it won't go to the Jihan Rest API directly, but rather be submitted to a blocking queue as a task. This will be producer part of the application.

Consumer part will do the submitting to Jihan Rest API, by taking tasks (user message) of the queue and sending the request.

You can make sure only two requests are submitted and returned per second, by submitting Callables to a bounded thread pool with two threads. Since Callable will block until it completes, you can time a second in between.
Alternatively you can use a synchronizer like semaphore which would be a better practice.

Answer (score 0):

I saw ilot's response and I agree with his suggestion. He already mentioned that using semaphores would be a good idea and I thought I would share a Java example making use of that library. I don't have any experience with Discord whatsoever, but hopefully you or someone else will find this example useful nonetheless.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class SemaphoreDemo {
    final static int TOTAL_REQUESTS = 10;
    final static int MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_REQUESTS = 2;
    final Semaphore semaphore;
    // the purpose of this array is for synchronization of the demo only
    final Thread[] threads = new Thread[TOTAL_REQUESTS];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new SemaphoreDemo().start();
    }

    SemaphoreDemo() {
        semaphore = new Semaphore(MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_REQUESTS);
    }

    void start() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.printf("Start sending...             [permits = %d]\n", semaphore.availablePermits());

        // trigger incoming messages
        for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_REQUESTS; i++) {
            messageReceived(new Request(i));
        }

        // synchronize with threads
        for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_REQUESTS; i++) {
            threads[i].join();
        }

        System.out.println("Done!");
    }

    void messageReceived(Request request) {
        RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler(request, semaphore);
        Thread thread = createThread(request.i, requestHandler);
        thread.start();
    }

    Thread createThread(int i, RequestHandler requestHandler) {
        threads[i] = new Thread(requestHandler);
        return threads[i];
    }
}

class Request {
    final int i;

    Request(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    void sendHttpRequest() {
        // do your thing
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Request " + i;
    }
}

class RequestHandler implements Runnable {
    final Request request;
    final Semaphore semaphore;

    RequestHandler(Request request, Semaphore semaphore) {
        this.request = request;
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // try to acquire one of the permits if available, else wait...
            semaphore.acquire();

            System.out.printf("%s: sending request   [permits = %d]\n", request, semaphore.availablePermits());

            // Simulate sending a request with a random response time between 0 and 3 seconds
            request.sendHttpRequest();
            Thread.sleep(Math.round(3000 * Math.random()));

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // the request succeeded or was interrupted; always release the permit so another request can take it 
            semaphore.release();
            System.out.printf("%s: received response [permits = %d]\n", request, semaphore.availablePermits());
        }
    }
}
```

This example simulates 10 simultaneous requests using a semaphore with only 2 permits. This means that when all permits are taken, the remaining threads that try to acquire a permit from the semaphore will have to wait until one of the permits gets released.

One of the results that I got was this:

```
Start sending...             [permits = 2]
Request 0: sending request   [permits = 1]
Request 1: sending request   [permits = 0]
Request 1: received response [permits = 1]
Request 2: sending request   [permits = 0]
Request 2: received response [permits = 1]
Request 3: sending request   [permits = 0]
Request 0: received response [permits = 1]
Request 4: sending request   [permits = 0]
Request 3: received response [permits = 1]
Request 5: sending request   [permits = 0]
Request 4: received response [permits = 1]
Request 6: sending request   [permits = 0]
Request 5: received response [permits = 1]
Request 7: sending request   [permits = 0]
Request 6: received response [permits = 1]
Request 8: sending request   [permits = 0]
Request 8: received response [permits = 1]
Request 9: sending request   [permits = 0]
Request 9: received response [permits = 1]
Request 7: received response [permits = 2]
Done!
```

Note that the requests may finish out of order, but there will always be between 0 and 2 available permits.